Bounding the Dirichlet inverse of $f(n) = e^{-mn}$.
Suppose we have an arithmetic function defined as $f(n) = e^{-m n}$, for some $m > 0$.
Then we have that the Dirichlet inverse is given by:
$f^{-1}(n) = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\Omega(n)}} (-1)^k e^{m(k+1)} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} e^{-m( d_1 + ... + d_k)}$.
The question is more so about what might be the best way to go about bounding this sum.
In a paper found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.12445, they assumed that f(1) = 1, and in Lemma 3.2, used the AM-GM inequality to upper bound the inner sum as:
$\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} e^{-m( d_1 + ... + d_k)} \leq e^{-m(k \sqrt[k]{n})}  \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} $ .
This might work well enough when you have $f(1) = 1$, but without that assumption you could easily have a very loose upper-bound that quickly blows up due to the $\frac{1}{f(1)^{k+1}}$ term in the inner sum.
This is really just a result of the fact that the AM-GM is a pretty weak inequality, except for terms very close to each other.
I was thinking it might make more sense to note that:
$\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} e^{-m( d_1 + ... + d_k)}=  e^{-m \sigma_1(n)} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} \exp(m \cdot \sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d \not\in \{ d_1, ... , d_k\} }} d )$.
And naively, one could then say that:
$\exp(m \cdot \sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d \not\in \{ d_1, ... , d_k\} }} d ) = e^{m \sigma_1(n) p}$, for some $p \in (0,1)$, and so
$e^{-m \sigma_1(n)} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} \exp(m \cdot \sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d \not\in \{ d_1, ... , d_k\} }} d )  \leq e^{-m \sigma_1(n)(1-p)} H_k(n)$, where $H_k(n) = \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}}$.
However, more than this, would anyone have any ideas of how to give a stronger, less vague bound on the remainder sum of exponential terms left in the inner sum?
I guess a good starting place would be studying this sum:  $\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d | n \\ d \not\in \{ d_1, ... , d_k\} }}} d$, (or alternatively the partial sum of divisors $d_1 + ... + d_k$), and trying to establish a meaningful upper bound. I'm sure there's also already some literature on this; if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.
I posted a slightly similar question already on this, so sorry for the repetitiveness in advance.

I originally posted an erroneous answer. But here is another attempt, this is the best I've been able to come up with as of far (and hopefully it can serve as a clarifier of what I was looking for):
Note that: $\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{k}} d_i = n$ and $\displaystyle{\prod_{d | n}} d = n^{\frac{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}{2}} \implies  \displaystyle{\prod_{d | n}} d = \displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{k}} d_i^{\frac{ \scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}{2}}  $.
$\implies \displaystyle{\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}} \displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1 }^{k}} a(d_i^{\frac{1}{a}}-1) = \displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1 }^{k}} \ln(d_i) = \displaystyle{\sum_{d | n }} \ln(d^{\dfrac{2 }{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)} }) = \displaystyle{\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}} \displaystyle{\sum_{d | n }} a(d^{\dfrac{2 }{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}  \frac{1}{a}}-1) $
$\implies  \displaystyle{\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}} |\displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1 }^{k}} a(d_i^{\frac{1}{a}}-1)  -  \displaystyle{\sum_{d | n }} a(d^{\dfrac{2 }{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}  \frac{1}{a}}-1)| = 0$
$\implies \displaystyle{\sum_{i = 1 }^{k}} (d_i-1) =\displaystyle{\sum_{d | n }} (d^{\dfrac{2 }{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)} }-1) + o(1) = \sigma_{\frac{2}{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}}(n) - \sigma_0(n) + o(1)$.
And then just applying this in the inverse formula:
$|f^{-1}(n)| = |e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\Omega(n)}} (-1)^k  \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} e^{-m( (d_1-1) + ... + (d_k-1))}| \leq e^{m} \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\Omega(n)}}  \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} e^{-m( (d_1-1) + ... + (d_k-1))}$
$ =  e^{m} \exp(-m(\sigma_{\frac{2}{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}}(n) - \sigma_0(n) + o(1))) \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\Omega(n)}}  \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \\ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} 1   $,
which, from the paper linked in the post, can be bounded as
$e^{m} \exp(-m(\sigma_{\frac{2}{\scriptstyle \sigma_0(n)}}(n) - \sigma_0(n) + o(1))) n^{\rho}$, where $\rho = 1.72865...$ denotes the unique root of $\zeta(s) = 2$.
This answer is somewhat ok I suppose, but ideally I'd hope to be able to bound the constant factor of $o(1)$ that pops up to know for sure how close the bound is to the true value. If anyone has any feedback or comments on this derivation please let me know. Thanks.

Why the downvote, what’s wrong with this?

What is $k$ in $\prod_{i=1}^{k} d_i = n $ ? What is the value of $k$ when $n = 4$ ?

So k refers to the index in the outer sum of the explicit dirichlet inverse formula: $f^{-1}(n) = \displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{\Omega(n)}} (-1)^k e^{m(k+1)} \displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{ d_1 d_2 .. d_k = n \ d_1, d_2, .., d_k > 1}}} e^{-m( d_1 + ... + d_k)}$. So notice how $k$ ranges from 1 to $\Omega(n)$, and for each $k$, the inner sum is over all $\prod_{i=1}^{k} d_i = n$.  $n$ is related to k only insofar as that $k$ ranges from 1 to $\Omega(n)$. Does that make sense?

And here $\Omega(n)$ refers to the Prime Omega function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function . So for $n=4$, $\Omega(4) = 2$, since 4 = 2^2, so that it has 2 (not necessarily unique) prime factors (both 2). So $k$ would take on values $1,2$.
